# strange shadows and artifacts on cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadows

I'm getting some unexplained shadowing artifacts after rendering in cycles.

[image: test image]

As you can noticeably on the end of the nose, and more subtle under the green eye.

I'm using a 3 point lighting system that can be seen here

[image: 3 point lighting]

I've tried playing around with the lighting, and no matter what I do with the lights, the shadow is still there.

Anyone any suggestions for what could be causing this and what settings I could try playing around with to resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are having duplicated meshes intersecting each other on your mesh, if not then it should be normals that are not represented correctly. Try to removing double and recalculate your normals and see if it helps. Also select all your face and apply smooth shading.

Attaching a portion of your mesh would let us help you diagnose the issue too. You could just leave the nose portion in the file where the artifact is showing up.

**Preliminary Probe**

Probing into the file, I found that you have meshes that have all the edges "mark as sharp"
to unmark the meshes. Go into edit mode, select all the edges ... hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> and select "Clear Sharp".

After which, I also found out that your faces are not joined as a single mesh ... to solve that.
Do this ... With all the faces selected , Hit <kbd>W</kbd> select "remove doubles". This will weld all the triangles into a single mesh and remove vertices that takes up the same 3d space.

At this point I apply "shade smooth" with the <kbd>W</kbd> "special meun. This mess up the normals. Then I proceed to add a modifier "Normal Edit" under then modify column. The strange shadows are gone but some harsh edges still persist.

**Solution**

[image]

**Note**
You can read about why this happens here. http://www.blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?370090-Cycles-Glass-render-Black&p=2864146&viewfull=1#post2864146

Comment: Removing doubles doesn't seem to do anything, and recalculating normals completely messes up the texture. Face is already smooth shading. Could you recommend a way I can upload my blend ?

Comment: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ use this link. Just upload the portion you need us to look at. Edit your original post and past the link in the Original question after you finished uploading. The upload page will spit out a link to your upload.

Comment: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/943/

Comment: When you had applied the solution did you notice any further shadowing on the tip of the nose? i still have that issue.

Comment: Yes I do have the issue with the nose , but realised it's just because the nose is really too pointy and would have cause shadowing issue without manually modifying the normals, what I did was just moved the vertice back a little and it solve the problem one my end.